# How to check Relative Source is available with String Path - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation, silverlight-5.0

I have some Path string like:

```
"/File1.xaml"
"/Views/View1.xaml"
"/Views/View2.xaml"
```

They maybe or maybe not exist in my Project. My project is Silverlight.

**How can i know they are available?**

Anyone help me please!!!

Answer (score 0):

simple you can use the File.Exists Method. :)

```
string curFile = @"/File1.xaml";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

If you think that your file will be gone after compiling than you could maybe write a separate class or app which checks for the file first.

Than you can do `process.start(yourProgram)` to run your code, than in your code just check for the new .Xap file

Comment: thanks, but it always return false with code in Silverlight Side. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thank you. 

I'm coding at client side. And i can't reach directly .XAP file is located server side.

I only know that file is located in Project at client size.

Comment: I do not get it. You know that the file is not on your pc, nor you've got any path to the file?
try my answer with the seperate class and run process.Start()

Answer (score 0):

File.Exists() works in silverlight.

```
if(File.exists("/file1.xaml"))
{
    //do things
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it always return false with code in Silverlight Side

Comment: you need to have the full path. also try changing / it should be \.

use [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + "\file1.xaml" as your path.

Comment: But i think, at runtime they combine into Silverlight.xap file. They inside .xap file. And i can't get full path